# How do I turn a number of vertex indices bigger than four into a practical way?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm working on a way to turn the information from 3d-files into THREE geometries. I receive them formated like this:

{"N":"name of the block","V":[[0,1,2]..[N1,N2,N3]],"F":[[0,1,2]..[M1,M2,M3]],"P":[[O1,O2,P3,..,Op]..[..]]}

N should be obvious. It's the name of the geometry.
V is an array of vertices.
F is an array of triangular faces.

So far so good. That's easy to convert into THREE geometries. P is the tricky part. It's an array of polygons. A polygon is in this case a face consisting of a number of vertex indices bigger than four.

There's no actual restriction how many vertex indices may hold, apart from the minimum of five.

Is there any working way to convert a structure like this for THREEjs?

Comment: What is the source? It may be using a format that has already been converted. But merely guessing would be hazardous.

Comment: this is not a three.js question but rather a data management question.

Comment: I think there are two THREE questions hidden in there: (1) how do I use models from <someProgram>? and (2) how do I handle non-triangle polygons? But first things first

Answer (score 0):

three.js supports a Face3 class only. It used to have a Face4 class, but you need something completely different to handle polygons. The short answer is no, three.js does not handle this out of the box.

A simple way to tackle it is to create a fan out of your polygons by fixing one vert, and looping through the rest, but this will work only on convex polygons.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_triangulation

Not a trivial problem.

Comment: Just in case you care, I have a solution now. The geo-json with the polygon should have never arrived at my end. The server is supposed to do the tessellation with openGL. Now I only have to handle regular three vertex faces, which is no problem.